# Explain get_template_part function

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, get

I am creating a website with wordpress and php. I want to include several files. Now I read that you can do that with get_template_part. But I still don't really understand how to use the function. Could anyone please explain it to me? Thank you :)

Comment: Documentation of get_template_part doesn't help you? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

Comment: I still don't really get it a 100%. I tried to use it but it doesn't work. Can you send me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer code here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

Simply

if you add "samplename.php" file in your template

you can get this file like

`get_template_part( "samplename" );`